# Returning a typedef defined inside a non-type templated class

Tags: c++, class, templates, typedef, non-type

I'm looking to create a non-type templated class with member variables that depend on the non-type parameter (specifically, fixed-dimension Eigen matrices, but the problem is present with `int` as well). To make things clearer I typedef'ed the member types, which worked great until I wanted a member function to *return* the typedef at which point I started getting the following error:

> myClass.cpp:10: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘myClass’

I understand, conceptually at least, that this has something to do with the fact that my typedef depends on the template and that as a result C++ is confused. The problem is I'm even more confused, I've tried some naive insertions of `typename`, but that didn't fix anything.

A minimum working example.

Header:

```
template <int i> class myClass
{
  public:
    typedef int myVector_t;

    myClass();
    myVector_t myFunc();
};
```

Source code:

```
#include <myClass.hpp>

template <int i>
myClass<i>::myClass()
{
  //blah
}

template <int i>
myClass<i>::myVector_t  myClass<i>::myFunc()        //<----- Line 10
{
  //blah
}
```

I'd appreciate any insight.

## Edit: Answer

As explained below the solution is to include the `typename` keyword in the implementation, but **not** the declaration.

```
typename myClass<i>::myVector_t  myClass<i>::myFunc()        //<----- Line 10
```

### Edit2

Generalized the question away from Eigen

Comment: Related: [Where and why do I have to put the `template` and `typename` keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/420683)

Comment: clang++ gives the following error message: "main.cpp:22:1: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'myClass<i>::myVector_t'" ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the name `myVector_t` in the definition of the function effectively depends on a template parameter, you need to let the compiler know it's a type with `typename`:

```
template <int i>
typename myClass<i>::myVector_t  myClass<i>::myFunc()        //<----- Line 10
{
  //blah
}
```

Comment: The fix is correct, but I think the explanation isn't precise: It's not the problem of `myVector_t` that `myClass<i>::myVector_t` is dependent. Try to declare it as an `int`, the same problem occurs (imagine specializations on the template parameter `i` would declare `myVector_t` as a data member).

Comment: @DyP [Seems ok to me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=776ba9a348be14c7ce8423ec96e70f1d-0746f3e88234b09a84c3eb092b83e0d1), although I don't have Eigen handy.

Comment: [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2cb19137f12b5244a75185b6dc304028-bb452bed83d06e87c370fcabced7e96d)

Comment: That's exactly what the answer is supposed to say - so I guess it's not clear enough.

Comment: Huh... So I tried variations of this, but what I missed was that you *only* put `typename` in the implementation of the function, not in the declaration as well... Thanks

Comment: @Jon: This use of `typename` only makes sense when there is a `::` token soon afterward.

Comment: @DyP My first minimum working example was actually with an `int` as well, but I'd gotten different errors on some of my fix attempts, so I'd stuck with the Eigen. I will generalize the question to make it more helpful for the future.